# @import CSS not working

Tags: css, import

I am using the [Chargify](http://chargify.com) service and within their settings they allow you to include some custom CSS. I am including

```
@import url(http://swag-box.herokuapp.com/chargify.css);
```

I can see that the CSS is being embedded into the page but It doesn't seem to be affecting the page in anyway.

[image]

You can view the live page [here](https://swagbox.chargify.com/h/3344970/subscriptions/new).

What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: CSS url subdomain is `swag-box` while link has `swagbox` (no dash).

Comment: The subdomains are different. That isn't a typo. They are hosted on two different sites.

Comment: Can you use `expression()` in your custom css to inject `link` tag into head with proper `href` attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `@import` is not necessary.  You can just do:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//swag-box.herokuapp.com/chargify.css">
```

The use of `//` makes the request use the same scheme as the page.  In your case the page scheme is `https`.  However, you were including via `http`.  Some browsers will considre this unsafe and block the resource.  *That* is why you were not seeing the import (it was working).  You can of course change the `@import` to use `https` or `//`.

You can also update the browser settings to allow the unsafe resource to be loaded, but this is a per-user setting.  If you are using Chrome, you will notice a shield to the left of the favorites star.

No quotes are required in the `url` declaration for `@import`.

EDIT: always use `https`

Comment: I'm unable to use `link` here because the service only allows you to embed CSS (which is why I chose to use @import).

Comment: did you try importing with https?
`@import url('https://swag-box.herokuapp.com/chargify.css');`

Comment: @KyleDecot that makes no sense; the URL does not care if it's included via `@import` or `<link>` since they essentially do the same thing.  You can ignore all that completely though.  If you really want to use `@import`, just change `http` to `https`

Comment: Well the reason I couldn't use `<link>` is because I the site only gives you a text box to put CSS which then gets put into a <style> tag (much like how MySpace) worked. In any case, using https worked. Thanks!